# iTerm2 Agnoster theme color issue

Tags: shell, terminal, command-prompt, iterm2

i am setting up my ZSH + iTerm2 with the Agnoster theme and seem to be having some weird Green line that crosses the whole Window as shown in the image below. How can  I remove this Line so it looks how it should, with out the green line[image: This is how my iTerm looks currently.].

Comment: can you add the content of ```Colors``` and ```Text``` settings of the profile you're using ?

Comment: This should probably go to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ .